# Locating prime numbers using for loop(s) in Python

Tags: python-3.x

So first of all, I realise there are much easier ways to get a list of prime numbers, but I'm just doing this to learn. I have a very poor understanding of a lot of this (as you'll see) so sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm trying to learn.

```
#make an empty list to store primes in
primes = list()

#make a variable to easily change the amount of numbers I test for primality
high_val = 15

#Allocate a range that I will test all numbers in for primality
for n in range(2, high_val):
#Within the previous for loop, start another for loop to test every integer against every 
#value inside the primes list
    for p in primes:
        if n % p == 0:
            print(%s is not prime" % n)
        else:
#If n is prime, I add it to the list and print that it is prime
            primes.append(n)
            print("%s is a prime" % n)
```

I don't know if those comments make it harder to read, but that's my logic. There is no print output for the function. So I figured, there's just no value in primes, I need to give it something to compare to. So I added a primes.append(2) at the start immediately after the first line, and changed the range to (3, high_val)...

If I do that, it ends up printing about 5 times for every number that it is prime and 5 more messages saying it is not prime. Clearly I'm doing something massively wrong, if anyone knows where I went wrong and/or how to fix this that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if `primes` is an empty list, why you're iterating over it?

Comment: I figured the first iteration would find 0 terms in the list, resulting in it thinking the first term, 2, is prime. That produced no results,  but as I said, when I added 2 to the primes list, it was even more broken if anything.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are missing some flags: you are printing if the number is prime every time you check it against another number. You should print it only after iterating over all primes.

About this, consider using `all`:

```
primes = [2]
high_val = 15

for n in range(3, high_val, 2):
    if all(n % p == 0 for p in primes):
        print(f"{n} is prime")
        primes.append(n)
    else:
        print(f"{n} is not prime")
```

ps: I didn't test it.